# How to make collision detection work when you have simulated gravity for your game?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision, detection

I am creating a platform game using pygame, in my game I have simulated gravity and platforms that can be jumped on but I'm having trouble getting the collision detection to work correctly. By collision detection I mean when my character sprite jumps I want him to bounce off of the bottom and sides of the platform that will be above him. Now my character sprite jumps through the platform and lands on top of it.

My code is as follows:

**My main class:**

```
import pygame
import random
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from camera import *
from os import path
class Game:
     def __init__(self):
          pygame.init() # initialises pygame
          pygame.mixer.init()
          self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT)) # sets the width and height of the pygame window
          pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
          self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
          self.running = True
          self.font_name = pygame.font.match_font(FONT_NAME)
          self.load_data()

     def load_data(self):
         pass

     def new(self):
         self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
         self.platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
         self.player = Player(self)
         self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
         for plat in PLATFORM_LIST:
             p = Platform(*plat)
             self.all_sprites.add(p)
             self.platforms.add(p)
         self.camera = Camera(WIDTH, HEIGHT) # creates the camera with WIDTH and HEIGHT of the screen
         self.run()

     def run(self): # Game Loop - runs the game
         self.playing = True
         while self.playing:
             self.clock.tick(FPS)
             self.events()
             self.update()
             self.draw()

     def update(self): # Game loop - update
         self.all_sprites.update()
         # collision with a platform
         if self.player.vel.y > 0:
              hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False) # returns a list of platform sprites that hit the player
              if hits:
                   self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
                   self.player.vel.y = 0

         # screen moves with player
         self.camera.update(self.player) # is the camera that tracks players movement

     def events(self): # Game loop - events
         for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                  if self.playing:
                      self.playing = False
                  self.running = False
             if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                  if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    self.player.jump()

     def draw(self): # Game loop - draw
         self.screen.fill(RED)
         #self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
         for sprite in self.all_sprites:
              self.screen.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite)) # loops through the all_sprites group and blit's each sprite onto the screen
         pygame.display.flip()

     def start_screen(self):
         pass

     def game_over_screen(self):
         pass

     def wait_for_key(self):
         pass

     def draw_text(self,text, size, colour, x, y):
         pass

g = Game()
g.start_screen()
while g.running:
     g.new()
     g.game_over_screen()

pygame.quit()
```

**my sprite classes:**

```
# will hold the sprite classes
import pygame
from settings import *
import random
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 40))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)

    def jump(self):
        # jump only if on a platform
        self.rect.x += 1
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
        self.rect.x -= 1
        if hits:
            self.vel.y = -20

    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC

        # apply friction
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION

        # equations of motion
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

        # stop from running of the left side of the screen
        if self.pos.x < 0:
            self.pos.x = 0

        

        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

**camera class**

```
import pygame
from settings import *
# A camera that keeps track of an offset that will be, how far we want to draw the screen which will include all objects on the screen. We are just shifting the drawing of our screen according to the offset. Camera needs to do two things, apply the offset and then update the movement of where the player is on the screen.
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, width, height): # we will need to tell the camera how wide and high we want it to be
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, height) # is the rectangle we set to keep track of the screen/be the camera
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def apply(self, entity): # method to apply the offset to the screen, by shifting the screen according to the movement of the entity within the camera screen
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self, target): # method to update where the player/target has moved to, updates are done according to last known position of the target
        # as the target moves the camera moves in the opposite direction of the target and stays within the center of the screen
        x = -target.rect.x + int(WIDTH/2)  # left to right
        y = -target.rect.y + int(HEIGHT/2) # up and down

        # limit scrolling to map size, keeps the 'camera' from going over the edges
        x = min(0, x) # left
        y = min(0, y) # top
        y = max(-(self.height - HEIGHT), y) # bottom
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height) # adjusts the camera's rectangle with the new x and y
```

settings module:

```
# Game options/settings
TITLE = 'Platformer'
WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 500
FPS = 60
FONT_NAME = 'arial'
HS_FILE = 'highscore.txt'
SPRITESHEET = 'spritesheet_jumper.png'

# Game colours
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# Starting Platforms:
PLATFORM_LIST = [(0, HEIGHT - 50,  WIDTH, 50), (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 1 / 2, 200, 30), (WIDTH + 150, HEIGHT - 50, WIDTH, 50)]
# player properties
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.8
```

P.S. added all my code for anyone that may need to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question says "when you have simulated gravity" but i don't understand how that would affect the bouncing. The answer below should work with your applied gravity so i don't think gravity will be an issue. So first, to bounce, we will need to know which side of the player is colliding with a particular side of the platform. For this the following functions can be used.

```
#Checks if right side of the player is colliding with left side of platform
def rightCheck(rect1, rect2):
        if rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x:
            if (rect1.y > rect2.y and rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height) or (rect1.y + rect1.height < rect2.y + rect2.height and rect1.y + rect1.height> rect2.y):
                if rect1.x < rect2.x:
                    return True
        return False

#Checks if bottom side of the player is colliding with top side of platform
def botCheck(rect1, rect2):
    if rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y:
        if (rect1.x > rect2.x and rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width) or (rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x and rect1.x + rect1.width < rect2.x + rect2.width):
            if rect1.y < rect2.y:
                return True
    return False
# NOTICE they take pygame.Rect as arguments
```

For your game you are probably going to need one for left of the player and right side of the platform well, but i don't have it since i copied these from my game. I am sure you can write one yourself :). So, moving on. The code below shows how right side of the player colliding with left side of the platform can be implemented. So you can do this with all the sides. Also, `bounce` function is probably the only one you are interested in, others i has to put there to make it work.

```
import pygame

win = pygame.display
D = win.set_mode((1200, 600))

def rightCheck(rect1, rect2):
    if rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x:
        if (rect1.y > rect2.y and rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height) or (rect1.y + rect1.height < rect2.y + rect2.height and rect1.y + rect1.height> rect2.y):
            if rect1.x < rect2.x:
                return True
    return False

class Player:
    def __init__(self, ):
        self.pos = [10, 10]
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50)).convert()
        self.energy = 10  #how much the player bounces to the left by
        self.trigger = False #Triggers the left push if it is true
        self.rightCheck = rightCheck # this is the function to check collision
        self.rvel = 0.5 # This is the movement speed 

    def move(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.pos[0] += self.rvel
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.pos[0] -= 0.5
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.pos[1] -= 0.5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.pos[1] += 0.5

    def draw(self):
        D.blit(self.surf, (self.pos[0], self.pos[1]))

    def bounce(self, platRect):
        selfRect = pygame.Rect(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], 50, 50)
        if self.rightCheck(selfRect, platRect):
            self.trigger = True
            self.rvel = 0
        else:
            self.rvel = 0.5

        if self.trigger:
            self.pos[0] -= self.energy*0.1
            self.rvel = 0.1
            self.energy -= 0.05
            if self.energy <= 0:
                self.trigger = False
        else:
            self.energy = 10
        

p = Player()

while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    D.fill((255, 255, 255))
    platformRect = pygame.Rect(300, 150, 600, 200)
    pygame.draw.rect(D, (0, 0, 0), platformRect)
    p.bounce(platformRect)
    p.move()
    p.draw()
    p.bounce(platformRect)
    win.flip()
```

It basically just checks if they are colliding and if they are pushes the player a little to the left.